# Concatenate for data frame R

Tags: r

I have a field containing some tickers, which is an argument of a function. Example:

```
aTickers <- c("GOOG Equity", "AAPL Equity")
```

This argument may vary in length; it is allowed to contain 1 ticker, 2 tickers or even 10 tickers. The data is retreived into a stacked data frame. I would like to split the data using the ticker information. I use the function

```
mX <- split(mY, mY$ticker)
```

I obtain a dataframe which is splitted, based on ticker value. As so I can use mX$'GOOG Equity' to call stock price data of Google.

How can I concatenate tickername with mX so I can retreive data in mX$'' ?

Many thanks in advance.

mY looks like this, for example:

```
               ticker       date    PX_LAST
    1      SPX Index 2009-01-01         NA
    2      SPX Index 2009-01-02   931.8000
    5      SPX Index 2009-01-05   927.4500
    6      SPX Index 2009-01-06         NA
    7      SPX Index 2009-01-07   906.6500
    8      SPX Index 2009-01-08   909.7300
    9      SPX Index 2009-01-09   890.3500 
….
    5128 AAPL Equity 2009-01-01         NA
    5129 AAPL Equity 2009-01-02    90.7500
    5132 AAPL Equity 2009-01-05    94.5800
    5133 AAPL Equity 2009-01-06    93.0200
    5134 AAPL Equity 2009-01-07    91.0100
    5135 AAPL Equity 2009-01-08    92.7000
    5136 AAPL Equity 2009-01-09    90.5800
```

mX$'SPX Index' for example looks like:

```
$`SPX Index`
        ticker       date PX_LAST
1    SPX Index 2009-01-01      NA
2    SPX Index 2009-01-02  931.80
3    SPX Index 2009-01-05  927.45
4    SPX Index 2009-01-06      NA
5    SPX Index 2009-01-07  906.65
6    SPX Index 2009-01-08  909.73
7    SPX Index 2009-01-09  890.35
```

Comment: Without knowing what `mY` and `mX` look like, we're guessing.

Comment: I do not see why this would help, but I have included a sample.

Comment: Please clarify your question and provide an example. `concatenate` is ambiguous. Also see that a critical part of your question does not print as you expected. Maybe you are just looking for the `[` or `[[` operator. For example, `ticker <- "GOOG Equity"; mx[[ticker]]`.

Comment: I guess you were right about the [[ operator. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Split creates a `list`, whose elements are the chunks of your dataframe and the names are given by the corresponding value on the column you used to split. Values like this: `""` (empty character string) correspond to *unnamed* elements; and `NA` are removed.

Example:

```
> d <- data.frame(a=c("A",NA,""," "),b=1:4)
> d
     a b
1    A 1
2 <NA> 2
3      3
4      4
> split(d,d$a)
[[1]]
  a b
3   3

$` `
  a b
4   4

$A
  a b
1 A 1
```

That said, you can try to access what you want using `mX$[[1]]`.

Comment: Ah, that's something. So I have to work with numbers. Many thanks. So if I want to apply a function, say mean(), to column PX_LAST in mX I have to use a for-loop which is something like mean(mX$[[i]]), where i is the iterator of the for-loop?

Comment: @JaapPaap if that is all you want, there is no need to split the dataframe first. Use `aggregate(PX_LAST~ticker, data=mY, FUN=mean)`.

Comment: It was just an example. Actually I want the mean-function to be a function which cleans up the NA. I do not want to delete the values, but instead I would like to assign their preceding value for each security. I splitted the data for overview. But if the above is possible using a nifty function I am more than happy to learn about it.

Comment: @JaapPaap you can use any function that takes a vector argument in `FUN`. Check this `?aggregate` or, if you're not afraid of downvotes/closing as duplicated, post a new question about it.